# C# Trying to get a list of questions from one class into my Main() class loop

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to call questions that I made up from one class and then implement them into my `Main()` method. The part that I am having trouble with is having the list read and looped through in my `Main()` method.

So far, it reads like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<string> askQuestions = Questions();

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(askQuestions[i]);

    }
}

static void Questions()
{
    List<string> question = new List<string>();

    question.add("q1");

    question.add("q2");

    //etc

}
```

I know I can get it to work if I just include the list in the Main() class, but the actual program will have hundreds of questions and I am trying to make it look a bit more readable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, you assign to a variable result of method, which doesn't have return type! So it won't return anything, thus you cannot assign result of that method to variable.

But your intention is clearly to return `List` in that method, so you should write your method like this:

```
static List<string> Questions()
{
    List<string> question = new List<string>();
    question.add("q1");
    question.add("q2");
    //etc
    return question;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you just return the list:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<string> askQuestions = Questions();

        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(askQuestions[i]);

        }
    }

    static List<string> Questions()
    {
        List<string> question = new List<string>();

        question.Add("q1");

        question.Add("q2");

        //etc

        return question;

    }
```

Comment: The return object of the Questions method

Comment: @HimBromBeere Well, the method returns `List` now, but the answer is no different from mine.

Answer (score 0):

I will do a Question Class as suggested in other answers if there are more properties than just the questions, if you dont need it, then something similar to this can help you:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<string> questions = Questions();

    questions?.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
}

private static List<string> Questions()
{
    List<string> questions = new List<string> {"q1", "q2", "q3"};

    return questions;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your "Questions" method's return type is void, Change the return type to list of type string and add a return statement.

```
static List<string> Questions()
{
  List<string> question = new List<string>();

  question.add("q1");

  question.add("q2");

  //etc
  return question;
}
```